# Python and PyQt5 Overlap of parallel processing functions

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I am working on a program that contains parallel processing, where it has to execute two tasks in parallel, and also every task must also execute two tasks in parallel, but when I run the program in the first when when executing one task the program works fine, but when executing two tasks there is  Overlapping information.  Is there a solution to this problem?
[image]

Code:

```
class thread_X_1(QThread):
        signal = pyqtSignal(np.ndarray)
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            var = Window()

class thread_X_2(QThread):
        signal = pyqtSignal(np.ndarray)
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()

            var = Window()

class Window():
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.pX_1 = thread_X_1()
        self.pX_2 = thread_X_2()
        
        self.pX_1.start()
        self.pX_2.start()

        self.pX_1.quit()
        self.pX_2.quit()
        
        self.pX_1.wait()
        self.pX_2.wait()

class thread_X(QThread):
        signal = pyqtSignal(np.ndarray)
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            var = Window()
            
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        
        self.p1 = thread_X()
        self.p1.start()
        
        self.p2 = thread_X()
        self.p2.start()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

What happens to me, is that when Qthread1 and Qthread2 are activated, in the normal case, Qthread1 should return Qthread1_1 and Qthread2_2, but this does not happen to me, but rather that Q1 returns Qthread1_1, Qthread1_2, Qthread2_1, Qthread2_2.

Comment: First of all, you're not using multiprocessing, but multithreading (they share some principles, but they're *not* the same). Then, since you're *immediately* using `wait`, and the python GIL doesn't allow real concurrency, you will still keep seeing the thread execution in the order of their creation. But this is not that relevant, the real question is: what is going to happen in those threads? Remember that CPU bound processing is almost always locking (the GIL issue above, which is a known problem with Python), so if you plan to do heavy computation there you'll get no benefit with threads.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I need it in image processing, I always say that multiprocessing is multithreading, this explains why the processing is slow even though my computer has 8 core

Comment: I suggest you to do some research on the difference between those aspects and the matter of the GIL, which is essential for understanding threading in Python. Btw, consider that your code has a fundamental flaw: starting those two `thread_X` instances is practically useless (remove `self.p1.start()` and `self.p2.start()` and you'll see): QThread is *not* a "thread", it's an *interface* to it; all instances of `tread_X_1` and `tread_X_2` will be created in the main thread. The only thing that is *actually* run in a thread is what happens inside the `run()` and whatever is called from there.

Comment: Finally, if you need image processing (which is CPU bound and as such blocking in Python, unless specifically delegated to a library that is actually able to work in multiprocessing), the only solution is to use *actual* multiprocessing, but to achieve so you need to work with data that can be *pickled*: treading uses the same memory of the main process, while mp does not, and the only way to communicate with another process is by exchanging serialized data (which is by converting objects to binary form, including bytes, and then reconvert it to usable objects).

Comment: @musicamante I removed `wait`, and replaced `QThread` with `Thread`, but the same problem, and to be more clear, I have two frames, each one showing a video, for example, one frame showing a video of a man, and frame 2 showing a video of a car, and what is required is to objects detection in each frame.  Frame 1 appears in Frame 2, and vice versa.. Can you write a code to clarify your words

Comment: Removing `wait()` won't change that much, both since your threads do nothing in your example and due to what explained above (the objects are created in the main thread). Switching to Thread won't change nothing too, for the same reason (the thread of object creation) and also because QThread and Thread both do the same thing at system level: they are *not* "the" thread, they are *interfaces*. That said, what you're getting has nothing to do with the creation order but the implementation: if your threads target the wrong widget, it means that you didn't connect their signals correctly.

Comment: I cannot write code based on that abstract explanation, as we don't know how you actually implemented your *actual* code. You need to provide a *valid* [mre], as right now your question has absolutely no relation with what you're asking in your last comment, it's too generic and those threads do practically nothing at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is not working as you want because in each call to thread_X() you are calling thread_X_1() and thread_X_2() in each one so as a result you are getting Qthread1_1, Qthread1_2, Qthread2_1, Qthread2_2.

You can checkout that in this code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QGridLayout, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QComboBox, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal
import numpy as np

class thread_X_1(QThread):
        signal = pyqtSignal(np.ndarray)
        def __init__(self,num):
            super().__init__()
            print(num,"1")

            
class thread_X_2(QThread):
        signal = pyqtSignal(np.ndarray)
        def __init__(self,num):
            super().__init__()
            print(num,"2")

class Window():
    def __init__(self,num):
        super().__init__()
        self.pX_1 = thread_X_1(num)
        self.pX_2 = thread_X_2(num)
        
        self.pX_1.start()
        self.pX_2.start()

        self.pX_1.quit()
        self.pX_2.quit()
        
        # self.pX_1.wait()
        # self.pX_2.wait()

class thread_X(QThread):
        signal = pyqtSignal(np.ndarray)
        def __init__(self, num):
            super().__init__()
            var = Window(num)
            
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        
        self.p1 = thread_X(1)
        self.p1.start()
        
        self.p2 = thread_X(2)
        self.p2.start()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

So probably **the solution you are looking for is this** where you check the thread you are going to use:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QGridLayout, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QComboBox, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal
import numpy as np

class thread_X_1(QThread):
        signal = pyqtSignal(np.ndarray)
        def __init__(self,thread_number):
            super().__init__()
            print(thread_number,"1")
            #var = Window()

            
class thread_X_2(QThread):
        signal = pyqtSignal(np.ndarray)
        def __init__(self,thread_number):
            super().__init__()
            print(thread_number,"2")
            #var = Window()

class Window():
    def __init__(self,thread_number):
        super().__init__()
        if(thread_number==1):
            self.pX_1 = thread_X_1(thread_number)
            self.pX_1.start()
            self.pX_1.quit()
            self.pX_1.wait()
            
        if(thread_number==2):
            self.pX_2 = thread_X_2(thread_number)  
            self.pX_2.start()
            self.pX_2.quit()
            self.pX_2.wait()

class thread_X(QThread):
        signal = pyqtSignal(np.ndarray)
        def __init__(self, thread_number):
            super().__init__()
            var = Window(thread_number)
            
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        
        self.p1 = thread_X(1) #Num of the thread
        self.p1.start()
        
        self.p2 = thread_X(2) #Num of the thread
        self.p2.start()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Tell me if this solution doesn't work for you.

Comment: Thanks you, I need the first code, but it shows: (`1 1`) and (`1 2`) and then gives this warning : `QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running`

Comment: @RACHIDBENABDELMALEK that's because `var` gets garbage collected. Change to `self.var = Window(thread_number)`. Note that this would probably change nothing, since the threads are still created and started from the main thread (see my comment on your question).